# where is the missing , before statement?

Tags: javascript

in this funciton when i use firebug i get "syntaxerror: missing ; before statement on the var url line.

```
    function makeRequest(){
                 var url= "contr_entry_pkg.sales_center_dropdown?&pnSalesCenterID=document.getElementById("pnSalesCenterID").value +&pvCurrCd='||CURRDEF||'";
                ajaxReq = (window.XMLHttpRequest)? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

                ajaxReq.open("POST",url ,true);
                ajaxReq.onreadystatechange =currencychange;         
                ajaxReq.send()         
        }
```

Comment: in the function call use single quotes or escape those double quotes

Comment: Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter gives a pretty good clue. I hope your editor has syntax highlighting ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the `"`in your url string:

```
var url= "contr_entry_pkg.sales_center_dropdown?&pnSalesCenterID=document.getElementById(\"pnSalesCenterID\").value +&pvCurrCd='||CURRDEF||'";
```

That will fix the syntax error, although I think you meant something like this:

```
var url= "contr_entry_pkg.sales_center_dropdown?&pnSalesCenterID=" + 
         document.getElementById("pnSalesCenterID").value +
         "&pvCurrCd='||CURRDEF||'";
```

Also, you should (though it's not strictly required) place semi-colons after each statement:

```
ajaxReq = (window.XMLHttpRequest)? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP"); // <-- added ; here
...
ajaxReq.send(); // <-- added ; here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeRequest(){
                 var url= "contr_entry_pkg.sales_center_dropdown?&pnSalesCenterID=document.getElementById(\"pnSalesCenterID\").value +&pvCurrCd='||CURRDEF||'";
                ajaxReq = (window.XMLHttpRequest)? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

                ajaxReq.open("POST",url ,true);
                ajaxReq.onreadystatechange =currencychange;         
                ajaxReq.send();      
        }
```